# How do I call a method with multiple parameters

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, cocos2d-iphone, void

hi I'm new to iOS development and i have a simple question.

I don't know how to call the following method.

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
 //do something here

 }
```

But when I use

```
[self ccTouchesBegan]
```

I get an error and it doesn't work.
I know this is really simple question but I can't figure it out by myself

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those are delegate methods.u should not call it manually.

more over u didn't give correct arg objects to it.

u have been using cocos2d

read it and make clear

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips:touchdelegates

Comment: Take some time to properly and professionally answer questions. This is gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call -ccTouchesBegan:withEvent: -- cocos2d calls it for you. What you have to do is define your own version of it to process the beginning of a touch. Read a little more introductory examples and you'll see how it's used. For instance, [How To Make A Simple iPhone Game with Cocos2D](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial) uses touchesEnded, but it's the same principle.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the rest of the method. You should do something like this:

```
[self ccTouchesBegan:yourTouch withEvent:yourEvent];
```

Being **yourTouch** of the type `(NSSet*)` and **yourEvent** of the type `(UIEvent*`).